# Flutter - GSL MEM ERROR using images in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

After loading several images in a listview, the application stops. It almost seems that the memory is not freed. In fact, unlike all objects no longer visible in the list, the dispose in the _ImageState class is not invoked for images. Could someone help me in solving this problem? Thanks a lot to everyone!

Comment: I think you should include your code in the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.